# How to write docker file to run a docker run command inside an image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a shell script which creates and executes docker containers using `docker run` command. I want to keep this script in a docker image and want to run this shell script. I know that we cannot run docker inside a container. Is it possible to create a docker file to achieve this?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y vim-gnome curl
RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xyz/abx/test/testing/testing_docker.sh -o testing_docker.sh
RUN chmod +x testing_docker.sh
CMD ["./testing_docker.sh"]
```

testing_docker.sh:

```
docker run -it docker info (sample command)
```

Comment: You can run docker inside docker. When started in priviledged mode.

Comment: Read https://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/

Comment: Thanks @Shibashis. Do I need to add docker:dind in my dockerfile? Could you please mention how to write my dockerfile?

Comment: What is the endgoal

Comment: Yes you will have to build FROM docker:dind or you can build your own image with docker in it.here is the dockerfile for dind image https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/f7ee50684c7ec92ce885c8b93a4ed22ddbb660f8/1.11/Dockerfile